# Is BasicDataSource.setValidationQuery() always safe?

Tags: java, sql, database, apache-commons

In using the Apache commons DBCP package, is using `BasicDataSource.setValidationQuery(String query)` always safe to use?

Let's consider this code fragment:

```
BasicDataSource bsd = new BasicDataSource();
bsd.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1;");
```

Is there any guarantee that a newer version of the Apache Commons DBCP will send this query to the database is connected to? What if a newer version, or perhaps even the `mysql connector` will use a small in-built SQL query engine that only handles SQL queries which are not related to permanent databases (So possibly selecting **basic** data or working **only** with temporary tables).

If so, what would be a good query to ensure that it will actually make a call to the database?

I'm asking this because I had an experience with this while using an MySQL client yesterday in which I was benchmarking something where a very simple query like `SELECT 1;` would actually not be sent to the database at all.

Comment: Select something that can't possibly come from anywhere else than the database? For example call a stored function with current timestamp as a parameter? Also: "Note: this method currently has no effect once the pool has been initialized. The pool is initialized the first time one of the following methods is invoked: getConnection, setLogwriter, setLoginTimeout, getLoginTimeout, getLogWriter." (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.0.1/index.html)